# Play buffer by PeriodicWave in Web Audio API, can I set Gain as loud as buffer?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I tried to play Oscillator (buffer -> FFT -> PeriodicWave -> Oscillator).

```
// PeriodicWave (-> Oscillator)
var wave = fft(buffer), periodicwave = ctx.createPeriodicWave(wave[0], wave[1]);
function fft(input) {
    var n = input.length, theta = 2 * Math.PI / n,
        ar = new Float32Array(n), ai = new Float32Array(n),
        m, mh, i, j, k, irev,
        wr, wi, xr, xi,
        cos = Math.cos, sin = Math.sin;

    for(i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        ar[i] = input[i];
    }

    // scrambler
    i=0;
    for(j=1; j<n-1; ++j) {
        for(k = n>>1; k>(i ^= k); k>>=1);
        if(j<i) {
            xr = ar[j];
            xi = ai[j];
            ar[j] = ar[i];
            ai[j] = ai[i];
            ar[i] = xr;
            ai[i] = xi;
        }
    }
    for(mh=1; (m = mh << 1) <= n; mh=m) {
        irev = 0;
        for(i=0; i<n; i+=m) {
            wr = cos(theta * irev);
            wi = sin(theta * irev);
            for(k=n>>2; k > (irev ^= k); k>>=1);
            for(j=i; j<mh+i; ++j) {
                k = j + mh;
                xr = ar[j] - ar[k];
                xi = ai[j] - ai[k];
                ar[j] += ar[k];
                ai[j] += ai[k];
                ar[k] = wr * xr - wi * xi;
                ai[k] = wr * xi + wi * xr;
            }
        }
    }

    return [ar, ai];
}
```

This code is good however this Oscillator's gain is standardized automatically. I want to set gain as loud as BufferSource (buffer -> AudioBuffer -> BufferSource), but it doesn't work I have tried using AudioGainNode, see [this test code](http://jsdo.it/Moriken/sfDX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createPeriodicWave` automatically scales the output waveform so that it has a max amplitude of 1.  This means the volume is lower than you might expect.  You'll have to experiment a bit with the gain to make the oscillator output match the buffer output volume.  The scaling depends on the wave used for `createPeriodicWave`.

However, I think the beta (or canary) versions of Chrome support the recently introduced parameter `disableNormalization: true` for `createPeriodicWave` to disable the normalization.  Then the oscillator volume should match the buffer volume.

Comment: I understand `createPeriodicWave`'s normalization is based on array that was transformed FFT(DFT), isn't based on volume of sound. Thank you.

Comment: However, `disableNormalization: true` is not true, e.g. if sound wave data array that has 2048 data and whose max value is 1 was transformed by FFT, the result are `real` and `imag` array whose upper limit are 2048, so `disableNormalization: true` can make the volume to  about 2048 times.

Comment: No, not quite.  This normalization isn't the FFT normalization.  The normalization is described in http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#waveform-normalization

Comment: Sorry, normalization of amplitude is not equal to normalization of volume.

Comment: True.  But if your buffer is a sine wave and you create a periodicWave from it to feed an OscillatorNode, and if you turn off normalization for periodicWave, then the volumes should be the same.  Or very, very close depending on the FFT being used.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* increase the gain on the Oscillator; but yes, PeriodicWave does normalize by default.  createPeriodicWave now takes a constraints object that enables you to disable that normalization.